# Django-like way to handle OAuth users

Tags: django, oauth, django-users

I am wondering what is the most Django-like way to handle Django's user model together with OAuth users? Specifically I would have mostly OAuth users (logged in using **social-app-django
** (https://github.com/python-social-auth/social-app-django)), some of which also have a password for the admin interface. All users should have the ability to save some settings in the webapp. Each user belongs to one or more groups.

#### Snippet of the problem:

Django users require a password to be set, but for OAuth users the field would need another value. This is for example shown here: https://github.com/joestump/python-oauth2/wiki/Logging-into-Django-w--Twitter After the successful authentification a user is created and logged into the session like this:

```
user = authenticate(username=access_token['screen_name'],
                    password=access_token['oauth_token_secret'])
login(request, user)
```

#### Two possible approaches:

#### A:

The approach from the snippet uses the Django user model and I can just relate the user settings to the user model. The downside is that the password and email are set to an arbitrary value (I also don't get the email from the OAuth provider).

#### B:

Approach B is to save the settings and roles in a table that is not associated with the user table (thereby not requiring email and password), but also loosing a lot of built in functionality of the user model.

Comment: Can you describe what exactly are you trying to do? Are you integrating "Login via Twitter"/"Login via Facebook" kind of functionality in your project?

Comment: You should use one of the very capable third-party libraries to integrate Django with OAuth; two good ones are django-allauth and python-social-auth.

Comment: I added some more information. I hope that clarifies my question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a different model for storing all additional data associated with an OAuth user and linked to settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL. 
It might require a custom OAuth authentication backend. You don't have to fake the password and email (just leave them blank), but have to generate unique username.

Check the sources of one of the third-party libraries, for example django-all-access 
https://github.com/mlavin/django-all-access/blob/master/allaccess/models.py 
https://github.com/mlavin/django-all-access/blob/master/allaccess/backends.py